# How do I get the correct signature for __new__ from the help() function?

Tags: python, documentation, signature

I tried the following in the interpreter (command-line mode? Not sure what to call it)

```
import datetime
help(datetime.date)
```

Note that the signature given for `__new__` is:

```
 |  
 |  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
 |      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
 |
```

Spectacularly unhelpful! How do I get the real signature?

`help("")` should give help for the built-in string class, but that doesn't work either, it does nothing instead of displaying anything useful.

Has the built-in help function been depreciated when I wasn't looking or something? I'm using Python 3.6.8 on ubuntu. It's much less useful than I remember.